# How to convert matrix to InpuArrayOfArrays in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, type-conversion

Suppose I have row of points

```
Mat_<Point> src(1,4);
src << Point(border,border), Point(border,h-border), Point(w-border,h-border), Point(w-border,h-border);
```

now I want to pass this row to [polylines()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=polylines#void%20polylines%28InputOutputArray%20img,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20pts,%20bool%20isClosed,%20const%20Scalar&%20color,%20int%20thickness,%20int%20lineType,%20int%20shift%29) function which accepts `InputArrayOfArrays`. In my case it should be array of ONE array.

How to convert row of points to this type?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [another](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=polylines#void%20polylines%28Mat&%20img,%20const%20Point%2a%2a%20pts,%20const%20int%2a%20npts,%20int%20ncontours,%20bool%20isClosed,%20const%20Scalar&%20color,%20int%20thickness,%20int%20lineType,%20int%20shift%29) form of this function with C arrays. The first array should be size of 1 and inner should be size of 4 and contain your points.

Also you can try the same and pass a `vector<vector<Point> >` instead of C arrays.

In OpenCV ArrayOfArrays usually means vector of something (Mat or another vector).'

Update: Also InputArrayOfArrays is just a typedef for InputArray. So you can try to pass a `vector<Point>`. It will not work for every function which require InputArrayOfArrays, but it should work for polylines(). I have not tested it, so please provide your results.

Comment: So I have `Mat`, why isn't is fit?

Comment: In OpenCV Mat is an array, not an array of arrays.

Comment: What OpenCV library function stands for array of arrays? `vector` is not OpenCV's.

Comment: OpenCV use vectors as well. Array of array is a vector of vectors or a vector of Mats.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will find it useful as a starting point. I spent almost a whole day looking for a solution. In the end I can draw with Polyline and fillPoly. I have to admit it was not a little annoying.

t2 contains 3 points .
So this add 3 Points  to pt.

```
vector<Point> pt;
for(int ao=0; ao<t2.size(); ao++){
    pt.push_back( t2.at(ao) );
}
polylines(image,pt,false,Scalar(255,255,255),2,150,0);
```

This to use fillPoly
just to fill a triangle

```
 Point pt[1][3];

  //set one point into pt  matrix

 pt[0][0].x = yourvalue_x;   
 pt[0][0].y = yourvalue_y;

  //set onother point into pt  matrix
 pt[0][1].x = yourvalue_x;
 pt[0][1].y = yourvalue_y;

  //set onother point into pt  matrix
 pt[0][2].x = yourvalue.x;
 pt[0][2].y = yourvalue.y;

 //adding 2 times (i have one triangle ) but 
 ppt  can  contains many more polygons 

 //const Point* ppt[2] = {pt[0], pt[1], ... };

 //i used only one triangle as a test 
 const Point* ppt[2] = {pt[0], pt[0]};
 int npt[] = {3, 3};

 fillPoly(atom_image, ppt, npt, 1, (255,0,255));
```